# How do you view the variables pane in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

In the instructions regarding the variables pane, pycharm documentation simply says:

> The Variables pane enables you to examine the values stored in the objects of your application. When a stack frame is selected in the Frames pane, the Variables pane displays all data within its scope (method parameters, local and instance variables). In this pane, you can set labels for objects, inspect objects, evaluate expressions, add variables to watches and more.

Well, what if the variables pane isn't there in the first place?  I've been using pycharm for 8 years but I rarely mess with the setting since they are so hard to remember where everything is. however, I had to reset pycharm to default settings and now the variables pane is missing and I cannot find it.

Also, there is a way to examing frames, watches, console and variables all in the debugger on the same level.  that is with one button click I can toggle from watches to console to variable etc.  but now it's set up such that in order to toggle from console to watches, I have to click on a pane which splits the watches and the frames.  but I don't want a split frame, I want to either see only frames or only watches. how do I solve this?

[image: debugger]

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, the "variables pane" is right there on the right. Or is that what you are calling "watches"? Will you give the link that you are quoting from to help us with some context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two places to look to see if you can get the layout you want:

1. The button on the right just below the minimize button. This lists the names of tabs for you to select in the debugging window. There is also a Reset Default Layout option here.
2. Right click on a tab (Console or Debugger) in your window. In this menu, go to Layout to select which panes should be added to the current one in a split frame.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know the answer to the second part of the question.  There's a way to put all four panes on one level and then you click on each one and view only that one.  An analogy would be like on an internet browser.  Instead of view 3 windows at 1/3 the size you can view each window at the actual size and the three windows are arranged into tabs.